# Pure CSS slider returning blank image on last slide

Tags: css

I'm working with a pure HTML/CSS slider that is returning a blank slide after the very last image as per this JS fiddle (https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ehKpi)

As you'll be able to see on this link (http://eavestroughcleaning.ca/temp.php) an image loads (3 in total) and slides into a 'blank' area holding for 5 seconds before reloading/returning to the first one. There is no javascript and you can view the source directly, however, here it is for good measure.

**CSS:**

```
    @keyframes slidy {
    0% { left: 0%; }
    20% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; }
    }

    body { margin: 0; } 
    div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
    div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
    div#slider figure { 
      position: relative;
      width: 500%;
      margin: 0;
      left: 0;
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 0;
      animation: 10s slidy infinite; 
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="slider">
    <figure>
    <img src="slider-img1.jpg" alt></figure>
    <figure><img src="slider-img2.jpg" alt></figure>
    <figure><img src="slider-img3.jpg" alt></figure>
    </div>
```

From my research it seems this issue is sporadic in nature and is likely browser or even possibly OS based however (obviously) I have yet to find a solution. I'm using Windows 10 (all updated) with Fire Mozilla Firefox (49.0.1). I also tried it in Chrome for good measure but alas coming across the same issue. Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: That is because the CSS code you use is for 5 slides and not 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already @gaby-aka-g-petrioli mentioned the CSS code is meant for 5 slides not 3.

Try this:

```css
@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }     /* 0 - 30% of animation time */
30% { left: 0%; }    /* 1st slide will be visible */
33% { left: -100%; } /* 30% - 33% slide change will occur */
63% { left: -100%; } /* etc.. */
66% { left: -200%; }
100% { left: -200%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 
div#slider { overflow: hidden; }

div#slider figure img {
  width: 33.333%;    /* image will be 33.333% of total width */
  float: left;
}
div#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  width: 300%;       /* total width of 3 slides (3*100%) */
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 10s slidy infinite; /* length of animation */
}
```

```html
<base href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/">
<div id="slider">
  <figure>
    <img src="austin-fireworks.jpg" alt>
    <img src="taj-mahal_copy.jpg" alt>
    <img src="ibiza.jpg" alt>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow. I tried your code and I've nothing. The page is completely blank: http://eavestroughcleaning.ca/temp.php

The images are there though: http://eavestroughcleaning.ca/slider-img1.jpg

Comment: Did the code snippet ('Run Code Snippet' button) work for you? Try putting some real images in there.

Comment: For testing purposes you could replace img:src with http://placehold.it/1000x572/ . In this case line: <base href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/"> would be obsolete.

Comment: Yes, started working when I gave it an absolute path. Thank you for everyone's help - especially karlisup

Comment: Glad that It worked out ;).I would appreciate if you could you mark answer as correct one. Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The slider you are providing is intended to work with 5 slides, this is why the slider has `width: 500%` where the last slide is shown only on the transition to it, then the animation is reset to the first slide and for this reason you will have a sort of "jump" or "blip" in the screen.

If you want more or less slide you should work on the slider `width` and set it as number of the slides times 100%. And you should also change the animation percentages to set the correct transition between them.

**Solution with infinite loop**

If you want that the slides are sliding like there is an infinite loop with a smooth transition between the last and the first slide, you should **duplicate the first slide** and put it as last slide, like in [this example](https://codepen.io/riccardo-andreatta/pen/rNxyYOM).

With this solution, when the animation is finished and the transition is on the last slide (that is in reality the duplicated first one), the `infinite` property in the animation is resetting and restarting it, and the last duplicated slide is replaced with the original first slide without any bad jump on the animation.

**Solution resetting the slider to the first slide**

Viceversa, if you prefer to reset the slider and see the slider scrolling back to the first image, in the animation definition, at 100% you should slide to 0%

```
@keyframes slidy {
    0% { left: 0%; }
    20% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: 0%; }
}
```